# Get friend list from twitter account in c#

Tags: c#, twitter

I want to get all the friends from twitter account. 
I have done following code :

```
        username = "username";
        password = "password";
        string url = "http://twitter.com/statuses/friends.xml";
        string user = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        Friends frd;
        List<Friends> lf = new List<Friends>();

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
        xmld.LoadXml(responseString);
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(responseString);

        foreach (XmlNode xmln in xmld.SelectNodes("users/user"))
        {
            frd = new Friends();
            frd.id = Convert.ToInt32(xmln["id"].InnerText);
            frd.name = xmln["name"].InnerText;
            frd.screen_name = xmln["screen_name"].InnerText;
            lf.Add(frd);
        }
```

But, i am getting null response. 
Should i miss something in it ?
Or any other better option ?

Comment: I tried with different URL : https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?screen_name=" + username + ".
I am getting error : "Bad Request " .

Comment: I also tried with : https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false. 
From https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/list.
But same error: "Bad Request".

Comment: Maybe using custom API for Twitter ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is all of the issue, but:

```
request.Method = "POST";
```

Should be a GET if you are retrieving.